# Example where $\lim\limits_{m\rightarrow\infty} \int_E f_m =0$ and $f_m(x) \not\rightarrow 0$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, examples-counterexamples

I am looking for an example of a sequences of non-negative and measurables functions with $\lim\limits_{m\rightarrow\infty} \int_E f_m =0$ and $f_m \nrightarrow 0 \:\:\forall\:x\in E$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Hint:** Consider $E=[0,1]$ and $$\begin{align*} f_1(x) &:= 1_{[0,1/2]}(x) \\ f_2(x) &:= 1_{[1/2,1]}(x) \\ f_3(x) &:= 1_{[0,1/4]}(x) \\ f_4(x) &:= 1_{[1/4,1/2]}(x) \\ \vdots & \end{align*}$$

Comment: Mistake in the question

Comment: @user203327 This answer is still correct

Comment: @user203327 Note that $f_m(x) \not \to 0$ for all $x \in [0,1]$ by construction. (And a bit more politeness would be welcome. "Mistake in the question" is not even a full sentence and *you* are asking for advice, not I.)

Answer (score 1):

On $E=[0,1]$, take $f_m$ to equal the indicator function on $[s_m,s_{m+1}]$, where $s_m=\sum_{n=1}^m\frac{1}{n}$ modulo $1$.  (If $s_m>s_{m+1}$, then instead use $[0,s_{m+1}]\cup[s_m,1]$.)

Comment: Mistake in the question

Comment: @user203327  The answer is still correct.  Moreso, in fact.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an easy one: just let $f_m = \mathbb{1_Q}$ for all $m$. $f$ is clearly not the zero function, but as a simple function it has integral equal to $\mu(\mathbb{Q})=0$.

Comment: There are plenty of $x$ for which $f_m(x)\to0$, though.

Comment: @Gaffney It's not so clear whether the OP wants *all* vs. *some* of the sequences $f_n(x)$ to fail to converge.

Answer (score 0):

The usual example I've seen here is the "moving block". Rather than writing a precise definition, let me describe the definition in words.

At stage $n=0,1,\dots,$ we will append $2^n$ functions to our sequence, specifically the indicator functions of $[k 2^{-n},(k+1)2^{-n}]$ as $k$ ranges from $0$ to $2^n-1$. So the first function is $1_{[0,1]}$, the next two are indicator functions of halves of the interval, the next four are indicator functions of quarters of the interval, etc.

Then the integral of each of the $2^n$ functions from stage $n$ is $2^{-n}$, which converges to zero. But pointwise convergence occurs nowhere, because any point is represented in one of the $2^n$ functions being listed at stage $n$.

Comment: It's a little bit confusing what you're trying to say because you're not being precise, but typically you need an indicator function to look like a sequence that converges in limit, but diverges in summation.  Because yours doesn't diverge in summation, there will be lots of points that never get touched in a tail and therefore approach $0$.

Comment: Mistake in the question

Comment: @Gaffney There's no error. We move across the entire interval from left to right with intervals of width $1$, then $1/2$, then $1/4$, then $1/8$, etc. Each point is hit in each full crossing. It's the same example as saz's, and in my opinion is actually clearer than saz's. It does diverge in summation because although a function from stage $n$ has integral $2^{-n}$, there are $2^n$ functions in stage $n$, so the sum of the stage $n$ integrals is $1$.